# caption at the begin of a table

Tags: tables, captions, tabularx

I am new to LaTeX. I took code for my table from different links, but now that I am trying to add a label I get error \caption outside float.

```
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=18cm, center}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} 
{ 
  | @{\hspace{0.3em}}X
  | @{\hspace{0.3em}}X 
  | @{\hspace{0.3em}}X 
  | @{\hspace{0.3em}}X 
  | @{\hspace{0.3em}}X 
  | @{\hspace{0.3em}}X
  | @{\hspace{0.3em}}X
  | @{\hspace{0.3em}}X
  | @{\hspace{0.3em}}X |  }
\caption{A Table}\label{tab:1}\\
 \hline
 
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I \\
 \hline
 A & 0.7 & 12.22  & $1.932 \pm 0.001$  & 12.46  & $1.826 \pm 0.002$ & 12.090 & $2.027 \pm 0.001$ & $1.928 \pm 0.082$ \\
 \hline
 A & 2 & 30.55  & $1.279 \pm 0.001$  & 28.26  & $1.341 \pm 0.001$ & 30.44 & $1.318 \pm 0.001$ & $1.312 \pm 0.026$ \\
\hline
 A & 3 & 44.22  & $0.8494 \pm 0.0004$  & 37.34  & $0.8886 \pm 0.0002$ & 37.91 & $0.8857 \pm 0.0005$ & $0.8746 \pm 0.0179$ \\
\hline
 B & 0.7 & 11.75  & $1.906 \pm 0.001$  & 11.35  & $1.885 \pm 0.001$ & 11.64 & $1.891 \pm 0.001$ & $1.894 \pm 0.009$ \\
\hline
 B & 3 & 46.94  & $0.8352 \pm 0.0003$  & 45.70  & $0.8807 \pm 0.0003$ & 46.96 & $0.8417 \pm 0.0002$ & $0.8586 \pm 0.0201$ \\
\hline
 B & 4 & 61,23  & $0.5590 \pm 0.0002$  & 61.83  & $0.5913 \pm 0.0001$ & 59.57 & $0.6298 \pm 0.0001$ & $0.5991 \pm 0.0290$ \\
\hline
 C & 0.7 & 11.27  & $1.828 \pm 0.002$  & 11.03  & $1.806 \pm 0.001$ & 11.40 & $1.841 \pm 0.001$ & $1.825 \pm 0.014$ \\
\hline
 C & 2 & 30.57  & $1.300 \pm 0.001$  & 30.60  & $1.272 \pm 0.001$ & 30.54 & $1.277 \pm 0.001$ & $1.283 \pm 0.012$ \\
\hline
 C & 3 & 45.10  & $0.7483 \pm 0.0004$  & 47.52  & $0.8156 \pm 0.0002$ & 46.55 & $0.8595 \pm 0.0001$ & $0.8078 \pm 0.046$ \\
\hline
 C & 4 & 60.15  & $0.6498 \pm 0.0001$  & 59.72  & $0.6469 \pm 0.0001$ & 58.99 & $0.6380 \pm 0.0001$ & $0.6449 \pm 0.0050$ \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustbox}
```

1. The main question is why do I get error when I try to add label at the beginning of the table
2. It would also be helpful if I get any proposal how to write the table better. It is very wide, so I used `\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=18cm, center}` to get a wider page for table. And then I also try to take away a bit on padding on the right `@{\hspace{0.3em}}`. But I am new and don't really know what I am doing. I will appreciate all advice.

Comment: The `\caption` and `\label` statements must come before tabularx

Comment: Never use `\adjustbox` for a table: you'll inconsistent font sizes, and a possiobly unreadable table. You' better print you table in landscape mode. Also, you can't have a caption because it is not in a ` table` environment.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to small but complete document with your table. `\caption` works inside `table` environment, otherwise you need to use `\captionof{table}{...}` defined in `caption` and `capt-of` packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided so far, I can see no reason for using a `tabularx` environment -- no less, one with 9 equally-wide columns. I can also see no justification for using the `adjustbox` hammer. I would use either a plain `tabular` environment or a `tabular*` environment. If you use the latter, be sure to omit all vertical bars. (Trust me, they're not needed.) Using fewer, but well-spaced horizontal lines will also do wonders for the legibility of the table -- see the second table below. I would also center the contents of columns 3 thru 9.

If you wish to use `\caption` and `\label` directives, you need to embed them, along with the tabular material, in a `table` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{array}    % for the first table
\usepackage{booktabs} % for the second table
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a slighly more open "look"
\centering
\caption{A Table\strut}
\label{tab:1}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5.5pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | *{7}{c|} }
\hline 
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I \\
 \hline
 A & 0.7 & 12.22  & $1.932\pm0.001$   & 12.46  & $1.826\pm0.002$   & 12.090 & $2.027\pm0.001$ & $1.928\pm0.082$ \\
 \hline
 A & 2   & 30.55  & $1.279\pm0.001$   & 28.26  & $1.341\pm0.001$   & 30.44 & $1.318\pm0.001$ & $1.312\pm0.026$ \\
\hline
 A & 3   & 44.22  & $0.8494\pm0.0004$ & 37.34  & $0.8886\pm0.0002$ & 37.91 & $0.8857\pm0.0005$ & $0.8746\pm0.0179$ \\
\hline
 B & 0.7 & 11.75  & $1.906\pm0.001$   & 11.35  & $1.885\pm0.001$   & 11.64 & $1.891\pm0.001$ & $1.894\pm0.009$ \\
\hline
 B & 3   & 46.94  & $0.8352\pm0.0003$ & 45.70  & $0.8807\pm0.0003$ & 46.96 & $0.8417\pm0.0002$ & $0.8586\pm0.0201$ \\
\hline
 B & 4   & 61,23  & $0.5590\pm0.0002$ & 61.83  & $0.5913\pm0.0001$ & 59.57 & $0.6298\pm0.0001$ & $0.5991\pm0.0290$ \\
\hline
 C & 0.7 & 11.27  & $1.828\pm0.002$   & 11.03  & $1.806\pm0.001$   & 11.40 & $1.841\pm0.001$ & $1.825\pm0.014$ \\
\hline
 C & 2   & 30.57  & $1.300\pm0.001$   & 30.60  & $1.272\pm0.001$   & 30.54 & $1.277\pm0.001$ & $1.283\pm0.012$ \\
\hline
 C & 3   & 45.10  & $0.7483\pm0.0004$ & 47.52  & $0.8156\pm0.0002$ & 46.55 & $0.8595\pm0.0001$ & $0.8078\pm0.046$ \\
\hline
 C & 4   & 60.15  & $0.6498\pm0.0001$ & 59.72  & $0.6469\pm0.0001$ & 58.99 & $0.6380\pm0.0001$ & $0.6449\pm0.0050$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Another Table\strut}
\label{tab:2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll *{7}{c}  }
\toprule
 
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I \\
\midrule
 A & 0.7 & 12.22  & $1.932\pm0.001$   & 12.46  & $1.826\pm0.002$   & 12.090 & $2.027\pm0.001$ & $1.928\pm0.082$ \\
 %\hline
   & 2   & 30.55  & $1.279\pm0.001$   & 28.26  & $1.341\pm0.001$   & 30.44 & $1.318\pm0.001$ & $1.312\pm0.026$ \\
%\hline
   & 3   & 44.22  & $0.8494\pm0.0004$ & 37.34  & $0.8886\pm0.0002$ & 37.91 & $0.8857\pm0.0005$ & $0.8746\pm0.0179$ \\
%\hline
\addlinespace
 B & 0.7 & 11.75  & $1.906\pm0.001$   & 11.35  & $1.885\pm0.001$   & 11.64 & $1.891\pm0.001$ & $1.894\pm0.009$ \\
%\hline
   & 3   & 46.94  & $0.8352\pm0.0003$ & 45.70  & $0.8807\pm0.0003$ & 46.96 & $0.8417\pm0.0002$ & $0.8586\pm0.0201$ \\
%\hline
   & 4   & 61,23  & $0.5590\pm0.0002$ & 61.83  & $0.5913\pm0.0001$ & 59.57 & $0.6298\pm0.0001$ & $0.5991\pm0.0290$ \\
%\hline
\addlinespace
 C & 0.7 & 11.27  & $1.828\pm0.002$   & 11.03  & $1.806\pm0.001$   & 11.40 & $1.841\pm0.001$ & $1.825\pm0.014$ \\
%\hline
   & 2   & 30.57  & $1.300\pm0.001$   & 30.60  & $1.272\pm0.001$   & 30.54 & $1.277\pm0.001$ & $1.283\pm0.012$ \\
%\hline
   & 3   & 45.10  & $0.7483\pm0.0004$ & 47.52  & $0.8156\pm0.0002$ & 46.55 & $0.8595\pm0.0001$ & $0.8078\pm0.046\phantom{0}$ \\
%\hline
   & 4   & 60.15  & $0.6498\pm0.0001$ & 59.72  & $0.6469\pm0.0001$ & 58.99 & $0.6380\pm0.0001$ & $0.6449\pm0.0050$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum to address the OP's follow-up comment*. Thanks for providing additional information about your document setup. I suggest you place the units on a row below the variable names; that will let still let you typeset the table in portrait mode. However, if your margins are much wider than ca 2.5cm, you may have to switch to landscape mode. This may be done, for instance, with the help of the `rotating` package and its `sidewaystable` environment; see the code below for an implementation (but not shown in a separate screenshot).

[image]

```
\documentclass[longbibliography,slovene,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set width of text block suitably
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\caption{A table in portrait mode\strut}
\label{tab:2}
\footnotesize % switch to 10pt font size
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercolumn whitespace amounts
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l l *{7}{c}  }
\toprule
 
Sample & $d$ & $M_1$ & $C_{p 1}$ & $M_2$ & $C_{p 2}$ 
& $M_3$ & $C_{p 3}$ & $C_{p,\mathrm{avg}}$ \\
& [\si{\milli\meter}] & [\si{\milli\gram}] & [\si{\joule\per{\gram\kelvin}}] 
& [\si{\milli\gram}] & [\si{\joule\per{\gram\kelvin}}] & [\si{\milli\gram}] 
& [\si{\joule\per{\gram\kelvin}}] & [\si{\joule\per{\gram\kelvin}}] \\
\midrule
 A & 0.7 & 12.22  & $1.932\pm0.001$   & 12.46 & $1.826\pm0.002$   & 12.09 & $2.027\pm0.001$   & $1.928\pm0.082$   \\
   & 2   & 30.55  & $1.279\pm0.001$   & 28.26 & $1.341\pm0.001$   & 30.44 & $1.318\pm0.001$   & $1.312\pm0.026$   \\
   & 3   & 44.22  & $0.8494\pm0.0004$ & 37.34 & $0.8886\pm0.0002$ & 37.91 & $0.8857\pm0.0005$ & $0.8746\pm0.0179$ \\
\addlinespace
 B & 0.7 & 11.75  & $1.906\pm0.001$   & 11.35 & $1.885\pm0.001$   & 11.64 & $1.891\pm0.001$   & $1.894\pm0.009$   \\
   & 3   & 46.94  & $0.8352\pm0.0003$ & 45.70 & $0.8807\pm0.0003$ & 46.96 & $0.8417\pm0.0002$ & $0.8586\pm0.0201$ \\
   & 4   & 61,23  & $0.5590\pm0.0002$ & 61.83 & $0.5913\pm0.0001$ & 59.57 & $0.6298\pm0.0001$ & $0.5991\pm0.0290$ \\
\addlinespace
 C & 0.7 & 11.27  & $1.828\pm0.002$   & 11.03 & $1.806\pm0.001$   & 11.40 & $1.841\pm0.001$ & $1.825\pm0.014$ \\
   & 2   & 30.57  & $1.300\pm0.001$   & 30.60 & $1.272\pm0.001$   & 30.54 & $1.277\pm0.001$ & $1.283\pm0.012$ \\
   & 3   & 45.10  & $0.7483\pm0.0004$ & 47.52 & $0.8156\pm0.0002$ & 46.55 & $0.8595\pm0.0001$ & $0.8078\pm0.046 \phantom{0}$ \\
   & 4   & 60.15  & $0.6498\pm0.0001$ & 59.72 & $0.6469\pm0.0001$ & 58.99 & $0.6380\pm0.0001$ & $0.6449\pm0.0050$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\caption{A table in landscape mode\strut}
\label{tab:3}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l *{7}{c} @{}}
\toprule
Sample & $d$ & $M_1$ & $C_{p 1}$ & $M_2$ & $C_{p 2}$ 
& $M_3$ & $C_{p 3}$ & $C_{p,\mathrm{avg}}$ \\
& [\si{\milli\meter}] & [\si{\milli\gram}] & [\si{\joule\per{\gram\kelvin}}] 
& [\si{\milli\gram}] & [\si{\joule\per{\gram\kelvin}}] & [\si{\milli\gram}] 
& [\si{\joule\per{\gram\kelvin}}] & [\si{\joule\per{\gram\kelvin}}] \\
\midrule
 A & 0.7 & 12.22  & $1.932\pm0.001$   & 12.46 & $1.826\pm0.002$   & 12.09 & $2.027\pm0.001$   & $1.928\pm0.082$   \\
   & 2   & 30.55  & $1.279\pm0.001$   & 28.26 & $1.341\pm0.001$   & 30.44 & $1.318\pm0.001$   & $1.312\pm0.026$   \\
   & 3   & 44.22  & $0.8494\pm0.0004$ & 37.34 & $0.8886\pm0.0002$ & 37.91 & $0.8857\pm0.0005$ & $0.8746\pm0.0179$ \\
\addlinespace
 B & 0.7 & 11.75  & $1.906\pm0.001$   & 11.35 & $1.885\pm0.001$   & 11.64 & $1.891\pm0.001$   & $1.894\pm0.009$   \\
   & 3   & 46.94  & $0.8352\pm0.0003$ & 45.70 & $0.8807\pm0.0003$ & 46.96 & $0.8417\pm0.0002$ & $0.8586\pm0.0201$ \\
   & 4   & 61,23  & $0.5590\pm0.0002$ & 61.83 & $0.5913\pm0.0001$ & 59.57 & $0.6298\pm0.0001$ & $0.5991\pm0.0290$ \\
\addlinespace
 C & 0.7 & 11.27  & $1.828\pm0.002$   & 11.03 & $1.806\pm0.001$   & 11.40 & $1.841\pm0.001$ & $1.825\pm0.014$ \\
   & 2   & 30.57  & $1.300\pm0.001$   & 30.60 & $1.272\pm0.001$   & 30.54 & $1.277\pm0.001$ & $1.283\pm0.012$ \\
   & 3   & 45.10  & $0.7483\pm0.0004$ & 47.52 & $0.8156\pm0.0002$ & 46.55 & $0.8595\pm0.0001$ & $0.8078\pm0.046 \phantom{0}$ \\
   & 4   & 60.15  & $0.6498\pm0.0001$ & 59.72 & $0.6469\pm0.0001$ & 58.99 & $0.6380\pm0.0001$ & $0.6449\pm0.0050$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But table is still to large to go inside my textwidth. Can I extend the table or is it just better to use landscape as @Bernard suggested in the comments

Comment: @Klemz - In oreder to address your follow-up questions meaningfully, it would really help if you provided some salient information about the document class, the font and the main font size you employ as well as how wide the text block is. Also, do indicate whether the column headers are truly given by A, B, C, ... , I. If that's not the case, do please reveal what a more realistic set of column headers might consist of.

Comment: I am using `\documentclass[longbibliography,slovene,a4paper,12pt]{book}`. Actual first row is `Sample & d [mm] & $M_1 [mg]$ & $C_{p 1} [J/gK]$ & $M_2 [mg]$ & $C_{p 2} [J/gK]$ & $M_3 [mg]$ & $C_{p 3} [J/gK]$ & $C_{p, avg} [J/gK]$`. First column is as is. There will be letters A to C.
The text in table can be a bit smaller. Maybe 10pt.

Comment: @Klemz — Please see the addendum I posted a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following redesign based on `tabular*`, `booktabs` and `siunitx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\caption{A Table}\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth} 
{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=2.2] 
  S[table-format=1.4(5)] 
  S[table-format=2.2] 
  S[table-format=1.4(5)]
  S[table-format=2.3] 
  S[table-format=1.4(5)]
  S[table-format=1.4(5)] }
\toprule
A & {B} & {C} & {D} & {E} & {F} & {G} & {H} & {I} \\
\midrule
 A & 0.7 & 12.22  & 1.932(1)  & 12.46  & 1.826(2) & 12.090 & 2.027(1) & 1.928(82) \\
 A & 2 & 30.55  & 1.279(1)  & 28.26  & 1.341(1) & 30.44 & 1.318(1) & 1.312(26) \\
 A & 3 & 44.22  & 0.8494(4)  & 37.34  & 0.8886(2) & 37.91 & 0.8857(5) & 0.8746(179) \\
\addlinespace
 B & 0.7 & 11.75  & 1.906(1)  & 11.35  & 1.885(1) & 11.64 & 1.891(1) & 1.894(9) \\
 B & 3 & 46.94  & 0.8352(3)   & 45.70  & 0.8807(3) & 46.96 & 0.8417(2) & 0.8586(201) \\
 B & 4 & 61,23  & 0.5590(2)  & 61.83  & 0.5913(1) & 59.57 & 0.6298(1) & 0.5991(290) \\
\addlinespace
 C & 0.7 & 11.27  & 1.828(2)  & 11.03  & 1.806(1) & 11.40 & 1.841(1) & 1.825(14) \\
 C & 2 & 30.57  & 1.300(1)  & 30.60  & 1.272(1) & 30.54 & 1.277(1) & 1.283(12) \\
 C & 3 & 45.10  & 0.7483(4)  & 47.52  & 0.8156(2) & 46.55 & 0.8595(1) & 0.8078(46) \\
 C & 4 & 60.15  & 0.6498(1)  & 59.72  & 0.6469(1) & 58.99 & 0.6380(1) & 0.6449(50) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the use of the machinery of the `siunitx` package. I've taken the liberty of uploading a larger screenshot of the resulting table; feel free to revert.

Answer (score 3):

Still another layout, with `siunitx, booktabs,multirow` and `xcolor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption, multirow, booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\newcolumntype{U}{S[table-format=1.4, separate-uncertainty, table-figures-uncertainty=1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, table-number-alignment=center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\centering\small
\caption{A Table}\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular}
{@{\,}l S[table-format =1.1]*{3}{SU}S[table-format=1.4, separate-uncertainty, table-figures-uncertainty=3]@{\,}}
A & {B} & {C} & {D} & {E} & {F} & {G} & {H} & {I} \\[1ex]
\arrayrulecolor{SteelBlue} \toprule[1.5pt]
    & 0.7 & 12.22 & 1.932(1) & 12.46 & 1.826(2) & 12.090 & 2.027(1) & 1.920(82)\\
  A & 2 & 30.55 & 1.279(1) & 28.26 & 1.341(1) & 30.44 & 1.318(1) & 1.312(26) \\
    & 3 & 44.22 & 0.8494(4) & 37.34 & 0.8886(2)& 37.91 & 0.8857(5) & 0.8746(179) \\
\arrayrulecolor{WhiteSmoke!80! SteelBlue}\cmidrule[3pt]{2-9}
   & 0.7 & 11.75 & 1.906(1) & 11.35 & 1.885(1) & 11.64 & 1.891(1) & 1.894(9) \\
 B & 3 & 46.94 & 0.8352(3) & 45.70 & 0.8807(3) & 46.96 & 0.8417(2) & 0.8586(201) \\
  & 4 & 61,23 & 0.5590(2) & 61.83 & 0.5913(1) & 59.57 & 0.6298(1) & 0.5991(290) \\
\cmidrule[3pt]{2-9}
    & 0.7 & 11.27 & 1.828(2) & 11.03 & 1.806(1) & 11.40 & 1.841(1) & 1.825(14) \\
 \multirow{2}{*}{C} & 2 & 30.57 & 1.300(1) & 30.60 & 1.272(1) & 30.54 & 1.277(1) & 1.283(12) \\
  & 3 & 45.10 & 0.7483(4) & 47.52 & 0.8156(2) & 46.55 & 0.8595(1) & 0.8078(46) \\
  & 4 & 60.15 & 0.6498(1) & 59.72 & 0.6469(1) & 58.99 & 0.6380(1) & 0.6449(50) \\
\arrayrulecolor{SteelBlue}\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]